# add static library to xcode project from command line

Tags: ios, static-libraries, command-line-tool

I have a static library containing libSomething.a and two.h file which i have to include in my xcode project for doing a specific task . I want to attach the library to xcoce project from command line is there way to do that ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a directly command line way, but you can write a ruby script to do the trick. You can use a gem called `xcodeproj` to edit the Xcode project file.

For adding a .a library, you may want to create an `Project` object with the path of your project file, then use the `new_file` method of the `Project` class to add it to the project. It is equivalent to dragging the same file to Xcode. For the header file, you can either add them as new file to the project (the same as the library) or just set the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` key of the `Xcodeproj::Project::Object::XCBuildConfiguration` of the project object.

For more information and usage of xcodeproj, you can refer to the [home page](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) and the [doc page](http://rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj).

Comment: Hi, I added a gist for adding the .a file. I will leave the header part for you to implement yourself, so you can master it ;). Good luck.

https://gist.github.com/onevcat/9342209

Comment: iam getting an error like this/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:217:in `normalize_source_tree': [Xcodeproj] Unrecognized source tree option `Frameworks` (RuntimeError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:176:in `set_path_with_source_tree'

Comment: The "Frameworks" is a group name already in your project. You can change it to the group of your own project.

Comment: `normalize_source_tree': [Xcodeproj] Unrecognized source tree option `hello`

Comment: I forked the gist by @onevcat and updated it to work with recent versions of xcodeproj. Solves the "Unrecognized source tree option" issue. https://gist.github.com/niklasberglund/129065e2612d00c811d0